# AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() not working

Tags: android, onclick, onitemclicklistener, android-adapterview

How to make AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() work, when

```
... activity implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener,
DragDropPresenter,
View.OnTouchListener { ... }
```

and I there is

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

to handle clicks? 
Idea is that drag and drop is activated on a long click, and the OnItemClickListener method is used on a short click. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcame the problem of handling short clicks by assigning each cell a tag and then reading the tag with the simple onClick listener:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();
    if (position = ...){ do some stuff }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit simplified but I hope that the example below will be helpful:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener  {

....
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    .....
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    .....

}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long id) {
....
}
```